# Where can I find all the milestones of the current Ubuntu development release?

Tags: development, release-management

Where can I find all the milestones of the current development release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table for the current and future releases of Ubuntu:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseSchedule

Table of Natty Narwhal milestones:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyReleaseSchedule

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether you meant the milestone release dates (as in the previous answer) or the actual images.  If you meant the latter, they'll all be posted to [ubuntu-devel-announce](http://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-announce) when they're released, and the most recent one or two will be available from [cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/).  However, we don't keep a full public archive of all the milestone images, so if you're interested in comparing successive milestones then I'd suggest you keep copies of them as we go along.